# logstash throw org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException when search a word

Tags: java

logstash can't search by word.
Exceptoin:

The query '* @timestamp:[2012-05-17 TO 2012-05-26]' resulted the following error:
org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchPhaseExecutionException: Failed to execute phase [initial], No indices / shards to search on, requested indices are []

logstash.conf

```
input{
file{
    type => "system_log"
    path => "D:\\application\\logstash\\logs\\*"
}
}
output{
    null{}
}
```

logstash deployed in windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is elasticsearch can't load the log file.

`logstash.conf` changed to

```
input{
   file{    
      type => "system_log"    
      path => "D:\\application\\logstash\\logs\\*"    
   }    
}
output{
   elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```